# What is a variance component model?

Tags: mixed-model, modeling

I was wondering what the definition of a variance component model is? I searched it online, and found it often appears with mixed-effect models, but couldn't understand what it is, and how it is different from and related to mixed-effect models.

Answer (score 4):

Variance component models "estimate the variability accounted for by each level of the hierarchy". They can refer to mixed (fixed and random) intercept models, in the form of
$$y_{ij}=\beta_0+u_i+\epsilon_{ij},$$
where $u_i∼N(0,\sigma_u^2),\epsilon_{ij}∼N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$ are the two variance components.

References:

- http://blog.stata.com/tag/variance-components/
- http://data.princeton.edu/pop510/lang1.html
- http://essedunet.nsd.uib.no/cms/topics/multilevel/ch3/1.html

Comment: Solid. I'd add (1) Variance-component models are explicitly designed to model within cluster correlations (2) as above I've usually used the term for random effects models without covariates.

Comment: Thanks, @charles! I completely agree with you about the first point. For (2), I think a) generally speaking the intercept is also a covariate; b) do variance component models allow random slopes (i.e. covariates for random effects)?